# Slice Layer in Caffe prototxt

Tags: python, deep-learning, slice, caffe, pycaffe

The last layer right now in my neural network is a convolutional layer, the output of which is a 4 dimensional feature map of size [n, m, p , q].

I want to know how I can split this into three feature map as shown in example below:

```
[n, :m+5, :m+5, :m+5]
[n, m+5:m+20, m+5:m+20, m+5:m+20]
[n, m+20:, m+20:, m+20:]
```

How can I do this using Slice layer in a prototxt file? If not prototxt, how can I do this in code? I need to slice it before I use the softmax function.

Please help!

Comment: if your second dimension is `m`, how can you slice `:m+5`? can you draw in a 3D cube what are the portions of the cube you wish to slice? it does not make sense...

Comment: I wrote a custom python layer  for this in caffe, so it worked out. Basically I wanted to divide a 4D feature map into 3 shapes of varied sizes like you would do in native python code.